# hg remove directory from repo?

Tags: mercurial

I'd like to remove a directory and all the files in it from a repo.

I have removed all the files with `hg remove`, but how do I remove the directory itself?

Will it just automatically vanish once I commit all the removed files?

Answer (score 23):

Yes.  Because mercurial doesn't track directories at all, only files, it only creates directories that have files in them, and if someone `hg updates` to a revision any directories that become empty are automatically removed.  So if you do:

```
hg remove directory/*
hg commit -m 'removed all files in directory'
hg update -r 0   # updates to a different revision
hg update tip    # jump back to the tip
```

That last update would remove the directory.  For everyone else it's even easier.  When they `hg update` to your new changes their directory will just vanish (provided they have no uncommitted file in it).

Comment: Caveat: if you have ignored files in the directory, hg will keep them there.

Comment: note, for me, running windows XP, the single quotes don't work for the commit message. you must use double quotes.

Answer (score 11):

```
hg remove dir
```

If you end up with empty directories and you want to get rid of them, an easy way is the purge extension. (add *purge=* under the *[extensions]* group in your .hrgc file to unlock).

You can then use

```
hg purge
```

to clean up the empty dirs... You must be careful with the purge command as it removes everything that is untracked in your repos. I strongly suggest you run a

```
hg purge -p
```

beforehand to see what the command will do ( -p will print a "test run" without doing anything.) Never forget the *--help* option! ;)

edit: I prefer using purge to hg update in succession as updating triggers rebuilds in my IDE if it is open (and it's a good bet it is when I do that). hg purge will probably be smoother. And you can use --all to include ignored files too (must be careful though).

Answer (score 2):

To remove a directory, Just do

```
hg remove <dir>
hg commit -m "..."
```

This will remove the directory and all files under it.