# How to remove folders from git (from other people's local repos when they do pull)?

Tags: git, version-control, versioning, history

So I have some folders that were tracked some time ago and added to the git history. Somehow, their content was ignored (gitignore) but everyone has them on their machine - I wasn't on the project from the beginning.

Now, their contents and the folders themselves are not needed anymore, but git doesn't see folder removal as an action.

How do I get git to record their deletion as an action so that other people get their repo cleaned up too? I'm a bit afraid of actions that change the whole history tree.

Comment: Is `.gitignore` versioned? If so: Remove the folders' paths from `.gitignore` file? Then `git` will see them and will be able to remove them.

Comment: Git doesn't track directories, so it won't remove ones that become empty as a result of a merge or other change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, as you noticed, [Git does not track empty folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10075480/6309) (because they have no content), one way is to instruct your colleagues to use [`git clean`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean#git-clean--d):

```
git clean -f -d
```

That will remove untracked directories in addition to untracked files.